# QlikSense Expression Displaying only Previous Month's Values

Tags: qlikview, qliksense, qlik-expression

I have started working with QS recently and I have a problem with defining an expression which will allow me to display previous month's data.

I have tried creating previous month variable:

`vPreviousMonth = MonthName(Addmonths(Max([Calendar Termination Month]),-1))`

however this did not work - retrieves value 0. Then I tried below: 

`If(MonthStart([Calendar Termination Month])=MonthStart(Today()),-1,0) as PreviousMonth` 
 
 which doesn't work either - retrieves current month's values, used in below expression: 
 
`sum({<PreviousMonth={"-1"}>} [Terminated])`.
 
Lastly, I tried

`sum({$<[Calendar Termination Month]={"$(=[Calendar Termination Month](AddMonths(Max(Date),-1),'YYYY-MM'))"}>}[Terminated])`

which, surprise!, retrieved 0 value as well.

Is there any way I can somehow make this work?

Comment: What type of values are stored in `[Calendar Termination Month]`?

Comment: In my dataset I had a column called `[Termination date]`, from which I have extracted month by using `Month([Termination Date]) as [Calendar Termination Month]`, as I read somewhere I should first have month extracted before trying to create previous month variable.

Comment: You should try the addmonths() logic with the [Termination Date] field. The function requires a date not just the month portion to work

Comment: Thank you for your remarks. I have tried `sum({$<[Termination Date]={"$(=[Termination Date](AddMonths(Max(Date),-1),'YYYY-MM'))"}>}[Terminated])` which retrieved 0 value. Also provided below `sum({$<[Calendar Termination Month]={"$(=month(AddMonths([Termination Date],-1))))"}>}[Terminated])` retrieved 0....  I am starting to suspect that first I need to do something with `[Termination Date]' column but I am unable to find any useful directions anywhere...

Comment: If you can show us some sample lines of the data and expected results that might help us to help you

Comment: What is the format of the [Termination Field]? Is it, for example, DDMMYYYY or MMM?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
sum({$<[Calendar Termination Month]={"$(=month(AddMonths([Termination Date],-1))))"}>}[Terminated])
```